# Adding fixed border around body

Tags: html, css

I have created a border around the website by using

```css
#top,
#bottom,
#left,
#right {
  background: #a5ebff;
  position: fixed;
}

#left,
#right {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 15px;
}

#left {
  left: 0;
}

#right {
  right: 0;
}

#top,
#bottom {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 15px;
}

#top {
  top: 0;
}

#bottom {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

Now this is probably a little bit outdate - is there a better, more optimized way to do this?

EDIT: Since none of the answer worked without any negative side effects or couldn't be used on my site, I went with @Mark Schultheiss comment and used

```
body{
      border: 10px solid black
}
```

but in order to have the top and bottom border always visible as well, I added

```
body:before{
            top:0
}
body:after{
            bottom:0
}
```

Comment: You could use _one_ pseudo element for this ... Positioned to cover the whole viewport, put _on top_ of everything else, and with `pointer-events: none`, so that clicks can pass through it. Only clicks on the actual border would then also pass through, so clicking _on_ the border could activate elements hidden below it. (Maybe a clip path to actually "cut out" the inner part of the pseudo element might also work.)

Comment: You are not really creating a "border" but more fixed blocks at each page margin with a background-color.  `body{border: 15px solid  #a5ebff;}` is that in one line BUT you might  make the entire page layout as a concept also.

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss that won't make the top and bottom border fixed though.

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment as where the border is (on the body) is outside the border/page size as this makes all borders that width/color etc. same as your background color on fixed sized elements at 15px width or height.  Make the body `height: 100vh;` perhaps?

Comment: FWIW borders are not really "fixed" elements are.  Starting to feel like an X/Y problem here.  I added the wordpress tags since you noted that only  in a comment

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss if I use body{border...} the bottom border is not visible when opening the page. And when scrolling down, the top border is not visible any longer.

Comment: In this case put the border around the body as Mark suggested, make it 100vh high, then put a div inside with y-overflow: scroll to hold your actual contents.

Comment: @fatpenguin exactly and still more of an X/Y problem as more information is revealed here.

Answer (score 1):

How about this one?

(I'd also like to read comments why this might be no good solution)

```css
body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 15px;
            border: 15px solid #7777ff;
        }
        /* forcing overflow */
        div {
            padding: 50px;
        }
```

```html
<div>my awesome content</div>

<div>more awesome content</div>

<div>even more awesome content</div>

<div>and some lipsum</div>

<div> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc auctor enim libero, id tincidunt elit condimentum vel. Suspendisse vitae rutrum sapien. Quisque fermentum dolor in risus lobortis feugiat. Ut a arcu vitae felis euismod egestas id sit amet lorem. Mauris iaculis mattis tempus. Quisque a elit imperdiet est gravida molestie in ac tellus. In pulvinar felis quam, eget cursus tellus faucibus sed. Cras egestas convallis pharetra. Vestibulum semper aliquet massa sed imperdiet. Aenean vitae magna euismod lorem vulputate eleifend. Mauris pretium tellus sed elit vulputate pulvinar.</div>

<div> Sed ultricies dolor in nunc fringilla fermentum. Proin egestas lacus nulla, ac interdum lorem auctor a. Sed lacinia mauris id dapibus convallis. Nam laoreet tincidunt laoreet. Nam lectus arcu, vehicula efficitur semper quis, sollicitudin vitae nisl. Nunc in eleifend ligula, nec eleifend mi. Aliquam id sem vel nisi porttitor egestas.</div>

<div> Aliquam eget tortor dictum, consectetur purus sed, rutrum est. Aliquam bibendum et dui eget varius. Proin erat sapien, feugiat vel vulputate quis, bibendum et nisl. Aenean porta purus arcu, non eleifend ante feugiat eu. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Donec lectus lacus, ultrices eu ex a, molestie dignissim elit. Quisque id commodo lorem. Vivamus sit amet massa vitae est ultrices volutpat.</div>

<div> Vestibulum ornare ac enim ac fringilla. Nullam ac enim ac arcu commodo egestas quis non metus. Phasellus suscipit arcu id odio sagittis, sed facilisis neque finibus. Morbi eleifend justo sed consectetur facilisis. Morbi urna turpis, feugiat eu ultrices ac, porttitor sed nisl. Nullam suscipit velit est, ac consectetur ante sodales at. Nulla cursus sapien sed quam viverra, vel tempor mi finibus. Sed euismod nunc dapibus, auctor tortor ac, faucibus mi. Mauris tempus ligula mi, id cursus orci aliquet eget. Mauris a laoreet justo. Cras nibh risus, tristique sed leo quis, rhoncus suscipit tellus. Sed sapien tortor, vehicula id molestie ut, rutrum id mi. Pellentesque ultricies luctus nibh interdum rutrum. Nullam volutpat ut elit quis molestie. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tincidunt pellentesque fermentum.</div>

<div> Morbi vehicula ante in justo pharetra, eget laoreet mi ultricies. Pellentesque volutpat placerat ante ac pellentesque. Donec faucibus tortor orci, eget commodo tortor tincidunt ut. Sed ut orci felis. Quisque magna augue, sollicitudin eget viverra posuere, blandit vitae elit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Curabitur maximus magna pellentesque ex finibus ultricies. Curabitur nulla metus, dignissim ullamcorper nisl in, consequat rhoncus tortor. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Curabitur aliquet porttitor turpis at scelerisque. Cras aliquam congue nisi. Sed tempor pretium arcu. Proin ultricies ligula ut nulla vehicula posuere.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply give the body a border or a wrapping div, no need for four separate elements. Also add `box-sizing: border-box;`.

See a simple example below:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 15px solid #7777ff;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>My Content</h1>
    <p>Lorem whatever</p>
    <p>Lorem whatever</p>
    <p>Lorem whatever</p>
    <p>Lorem whatever</p>
    <p>Lorem whatever</p>
    <p>Lorem whatever</p>
    <p>Lorem whatever</p>
    <p>Lorem whatever</p>
    <p>Lorem whatever</p>
    <p>Lorem whatever</p>
    <p>Lorem whatever</p>
    <p>Lorem whatever</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here is an alternative solution which does not need the extra div based on my earlier answer. Thanks @Gunnar

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

body {
  padding: 15px; border: 15px solid #7777ff;
}
```

```html
<h1>My Content</h1>
<p>Lorem whatever</p>
<p>Lorem whatever</p>
<p>Lorem whatever</p>
<p>Lorem whatever</p>
<p>Lorem whatever</p>
<p>Lorem whatever</p>
<p>Lorem whatever</p>
<p>Lorem whatever</p>
<p>Lorem whatever</p>
<p>Lorem whatever</p>
<p>Lorem whatever</p>
<p>Lorem whatever</p>
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  
}

#left,#right,#bottom {
  display: none;
}

#top {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 15px solid #aaaaff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1, p { padding: 10px 30px 0; }
```

```html
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="bottom"></div>

<h1>Headline</h1>
<p>Content content content, content.</p>
<p>Content content content, content.</p>
<p>Content content content, content.</p>
<p>Content content content, content.</p>
<p>Content content content, content.</p>
<p>Content content content, content.</p>
<p>Content content content, content.</p>
<p>Content content content, content.</p>
<p>Content content content, content.</p>
<p>Content content content, content.</p>
<p>Content content content, content.</p>
<p>Content content content, content.</p>
<p>Content content content, content.</p>
<p>Content content content, content.</p>
<p>Content content content, content.</p>
<p>Content content content, content.</p>
<p>Content content content, content.</p>
```

Comment: And what happens if the content of the body is larger than 100%?

Comment: In that case the body would expand and the browser lets you scroll. Unless you specify `overflow: hidden;` and implement scrolling yourself or something like that. You can take my couple lines of html/css and just try it out.

Comment: As the other answers have pointed out, a div works too. Main point is: Yes you don't need four HTML elements, simpy give one wrapping element a border.

Comment: State of the art I'd say.

Comment: I updated the answer to use the wrapping div - it handles overflow a bit better with `overflow: scroll`.

Comment: @PeterKrebs I liked your first style but I see the problem it had. how about this css? * {margin: 0; padding: 0;} html {height: 100%; max-height: 100%;} body {padding: 15px; border: 15px solid #7777ff;}

Comment: @PeterKrebs I am using a Wordpress theme and can't edit the html really. And with your way my footer also has padding.

Comment: Well put the relevant HTML in the question, including the footer. You'll get more precise answers. You could just remove extra padding with `padding-bottom`, `padding-top` and the like. Open browser developer tools.

Comment: @maw I added the html tag only solution again for you to this answer.

Comment: @PeterKrebs this does not work for twpo reasons: 1. The top and bottom border aren't visible all time, for exampe once you start scrolling the top border disappears, and 2. it also puts a padding around the footer.

Comment: @maw I see you want the border to be fixed positioning. Updated my answer for that as well. I can't know what the code does to your footer - please post your HTML (can be without content, just the tags if need be). Otherwise just understand you can use `box-sizing: border-box;` and use a `border` to just have one div instead of four.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest creating a div with the border you need so to avoid creating 4 elements just for this.

```css
.border {
  border: #a5ebff 15px solid;
  position: fixed;
  inset: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="border"></div>
```

This is a lot less code for the same result.

As a sidenote, avoid using css on ids, its better to use a class.

Comment: Fine answer otherwise, but "avoid using css on ids, its better to use a class" is strange advice.

Comment: @Tets Tets this makes all links on the page unclickable.

Answer (score -1):

This is often called a "holy grail" layout or similar with 5 main sections.  Keep or remove those you need.  Ugly here just to show what is where.

Using grid layout we can either use names or as I did `grid-column` to put stuff in the grid.

I put a comment where the border specific to the question was placed.  Note using grid like this avoids the challenges with layout seen by using fixed or other positioning which gets out of hand quickly as the layout grows and this is more responsive on phones etc.

```css
body {
  /*set some defaults */
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100vh;
}

.section {
  border: dashed green 3px;
}

.page-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: auto 1fr auto / auto 1fr auto;
  /* question specific put a border around it; light blue in this case */
  border: solid 1em #a5ebff;
}

.header-container {
  padding: 2em;
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
}

.left-container {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}

.content-container {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
}

.right-container {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
}

.footer-container {
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
}


/* just style below here */

.header-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
  background-color: #ff222222;
}

.header-container .title {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.right-container {
  background-color: #ffff2222;
}

.left-container {
  background-color: #ff222222;
}

.content-container {
  /*super center the content */
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #2222ff22;
}

.footer-container {
  background-color: #22222222;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-container">
  <header class="section header-container">
    <div class="title">Header</div>
    <div class="other-thing">Other</div>
  </header>
  <div class="blue section left-container">Left Sidebar</div>
  <main class="section coral content-container"> Main Content</main>
  <div class=" yellow section right-container">Right Sidebar</div>
  <footer class="green section footer-container">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `:before` with `position: fixed`:

```css
body {
  --body-border-width: 24px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: var(--body-border-width);
}

body:before {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  inset: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  border: solid var(--body-border-width) purple;
}

/* debug */
body div {
  height: 200vh;
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro, laudantium totam quasi in magnam facere modi consequuntur provident consequatur ipsam.</div>
```